# How to set the magnitude of the colors in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have used the DensityPLot to show two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ in different regions. I want to combine them using the Show function. The problem is, the colors are not consistent in the two different plots. For example, regions where the magnitude of the function $f_1$ is equal to one is shown by red, while regions where the magnitude of the function $f_2$ is equal to one is shown by blue. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should set the scaling manually in both plots. It can be done by specifying `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {min, max}}]` where `min` and `max` are the endpoints of your domain.

Comment: It doesn't work. @C.E. and still shows different colors for the same values in different plots

Comment: Please post your code and I’ll tell you why it doesn’t work.

Comment: You might want to leverage [`ColorFunctionScaling -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) with some manual plot-range and scaling controls.